# Rails returning my data, but not in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making an api call in a rails app that I expect to return an array. I have two models involved. A `Document` has_many `document_versions` and a `DocumentVersion` belongs_to `document`. I am including Her::Model in both of these models.

When I make the api call to get a list of documents, it returns an array that I can `.each` over for the documents. But I can't iterate over each document's document_versions. The data is in there, but not as an array. When I debug to show document[:document_versions], it show this:

```
--- !ruby/object:Her::Model::Relation
parent: !ruby/class 'Api::DocumentVersion'
params:
  :client_id: 1
  :document_id: 1
_fetch: !ruby/array:Her::Collection
  internal:
  - !ruby/object:Api::DocumentVersion
    metadata: {}
    response_errors: {}
    destroyed: false
    attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      id: 1
      doc_id: 1
      file_name: thisFile.txt
      file_date: '2014-01-01 12:00:00'
      who_uploaded: 1
    changed_attributes:
      id: 
      doc_id: 
      file_name: 
      file_date: 
      who_uploaded: 
  - !ruby/object:Api::DocumentVersion
    metadata: {}
    response_errors: {}
    destroyed: false
    attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      id: 2
      doc_id: 1
      file_name: thisFile_2.txt
      file_date: '2015-01-01 12:00:00'
      who_uploaded: 1
    changed_attributes:
      id: 
      doc_id: 
      file_name: 
      file_date: 
      who_uploaded:
```

So that's the data I want, but I want to be able to do something like `document.document_versions.each do |version| ...`
but when I try that, I get the error `can't convert Array into Hash`

How can I turn this result into something I can loop over?

Comment: Where's the YAML coming from?

Comment: Is that YAML that I posted? I'm a rails beginner. that big chunk of data is what I see with <%= debug document[:document_versions] %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://github.com/remiprev/her/issues/196) and used the suggestion given there to modify my DocumentVersion model. I added

```
def initialize(document_version)
  super(document_version: document_version)
end
```

Now I can do
`<% document.document_versions.each do |version| %>`